# Use of unresolved identifier 'OAuthProvider'

Tags: swift

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple

I'm following guide in firebase apple login, and I got error 'Use of unresolved identifier 'OAuthProvider' even though I have included Firebase.

```
extension SignInWithAppleDelegates: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    switch authorization.credential {
    case let appleIdCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
      if let _ = appleIdCredential.email, let _ = appleIdCredential.fullName {
        displayLog(credential: appleIdCredential)
      }
      signInSucceeded(true)

    default:
      break
    }


    // Initialize a Firebase credential.
    let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                              idToken: idTokenString,
                                              rawNonce: nonce)
    // Sign in with Firebase.
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
      if error {
        // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
        // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
        // your request to Apple.
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
      }
      // User is signed in to Firebase with Apple.
      // ...
    }
  }
```

pod 'Firebase' is how I installed my firebase module.

Answer (score 3):

pod 'Firebase/Auth' was the solution. And in swift file, you have to 
`import FirebaseAuth`